# WCSession communication delayed/unreliable in iOS/watchOS simulator

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch

After upgrading to XCode 8, I had an app update rejected because a button in the watch app wasn't having an effect on the iOS app. Re-running in the simulator, it seemed that sending messages via WCSession was occasionally failing without error on one machine, and almost always on another I use.

I've created a simple app that replicates the behavior, with a button and counter in both the iOS and watch apps. The intention is that tapping the button in the iOS app will increment the counter in the watch app and vice versa.

A few times when I've left the apps running a while, the messages were eventually delivered (after about 2 minutes).

iOS App ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WCSessionDelegate {
    var count: Int = 0
    var watchSession: WCSession?    
    @IBOutlet var countLabel: UILabel?

    @IBAction func sendMessage(sender: AnyObject) {
        watchSession?.sendMessage(
            ["message":"increment"],
            replyHandler: { (message: [String : Any]) in
            },
            errorHandler: { (err: Error) in
        })
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if(WCSession.isSupported()){
            watchSession = WCSession.default()
            watchSession!.delegate = self
            watchSession!.activate()
        }
    }

    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any], replyHandler: @escaping ([String : Any]) -> Void) {
        count+=1
        updateView()
        replyHandler([:])
    }

    func updateView(){
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.countLabel?.text = ("\(self.count)")
        }
    }

    func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {}
    func sessionDidBecomeInactive(_ session: WCSession){}
    func sessionDidDeactivate(_ session: WCSession){}
}
```

watchOS InterfaceController:

```
class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController, WCSessionDelegate {
    var count: Int = 0
    var watchSession : WCSession?
    @IBOutlet var countLabel: WKInterfaceLabel?

    @IBAction func sendMessage(sender: AnyObject) {
        watchSession?.sendMessage(
            ["message":"increment"],
            replyHandler: { (message: [String : Any]) in
            },
            errorHandler: { (err: Error) in
        })
    }

    override func willActivate() {
        super.willActivate()
        if(WCSession.isSupported()){
            watchSession = WCSession.default()
            watchSession!.delegate = self
            watchSession!.activate()
        }
    }

    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any], replyHandler: @escaping ([String : Any]) -> Void) {
        count+=1
        updateView()
        replyHandler([:])
    }

    func updateView(){
        countLabel?.setText("\(self.count)")
    }

    func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {}
}
```

Comment: The simulator has some behavioral differences from actual devices, and I've found often has more/different bugs. I'd suggest testing on real devices primarily and using the simulators for quick little tests or sanity testing

Comment: I'd been planning to test on my device when I got some time, and it seems to be working perfectly. I'm not too comfortable with the idea of submitting something that doesn't work in the simulator, but guess I have no choice. Will also report this as a bug in the simulator, since it's wasted a lot of my time.